# How to add_index after migrated in Rail 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

Sorry, I not familiar to Rails.
I just wanna know how to apply add_index , after I've already done the migration file by db:migrate

```
add_index :categories_products,
          [:category_id, :product_id], unique: true
```

I tried to edit the migrate and go db:migrate ,  it seems nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if all you want to do is edit the migration, and re-migrate try this:

if you only need to go back one migration:

```
rake db:rollback
```

or if you need to step back, multiple migrations:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=3
```

Then, edit your migration to add the index, and finish it off with:

```
rake db:migrate
```

hope that helps! :-)